# Change Windows 8.1 password: windows chroot equivalent?

Tags: windows-8, passwords

Trust me I scoured the net. Long story short, I was tasked to remove/change a forgotten Administrator password of a Windows 8.1 UEFI laptop computer (ASUS T100TA-DK005H). I thought it was easy as removing passwords with NT Offline Registry Editor in previous Windows versions.

Now using Macrium Reflect and at the command prompt (live USB). If im not mistaken I am currently using the live USB's system. However I want to perform `net user Administrator *` to change the password **of the local Windows 8.1 admin account**. In linux you will have to chroot to the filesystem in order to do that.

Now my question is - is there a chroot equivalent for Windows partitions in order to perform a 'net user Someone *' command to?

No password reset disk.
Forgotten/unregistered Microsoft account.
No PIN.
Reset/refresh/advanced etc. won't work (as this is the only admin account and whose password is forgotten)

Comment: No. `net user` is only for running systems. For an offline system, either use one of the existing password reset tools, of which there are many, or manually mount and edit the SAM registry hive.

Comment: im afraid there aren't any reset tools available for me at this moment and have to do things in cmd. Otherwise, i will have to try another live ISO that works on UEFI USB3.0

Comment: @WikiWitz Or you could just pull the HDD and hook it to another system that does have the tools.

Comment: its a transformer netbook and the HDD is in the tablet (is this correct?) and i dont have a adapter right now. Check the model I wrote above.

Comment: Did you try running the Offline NT P&R utility after disabling Secure Boot/enabling legacy BIOS? The actual option name depends on the manufacturer. Also, do you have access to another Windows system?

Comment: part of the problem is the bios/uefi setup. it doesn't let provide options for legacy boot. it can disable secure boot but only boots uefi bootable usb sticks.

Comment: @WikiWitz Have you considered a Linux LiveUSB? I believe Knoppix, which was designed to be a recovery system, can reset Windows passwords. You could grab any other UEFI-compatible Linux LiveUSB distro and add a password reset tool to it.